# Why does Larry Benson raise the "disclaimer" topic in this scene in Small Soldiers?

Tags: character-motivation, small-soldiers-1998

In the science fiction movie *Small Soldiers* (1998), Larry Benson presents his idea for the Commando Elite, a special task force of sentient action figures to GloboTech CEO Gil Mars. He shows Gil Mars the demonstration video of Commando Elite in which the toys punch out of the box:

> Gil Mars: Can they really do that?
>
> Larry Benson: Do what?
>
> Gil Mars: Punch out of the box.
>
> Larry Benson: No. I didn't think so.
>   There's a **disclaimer**. Legal says we're completely covered.

**Why did Larry bring up the topic of a disclaimer when discussing the toys being unable to punch out of the box?**

Comment: Are you asking what a disclaimer is? Or why a product being shown to do something it really can't do needs a disclaimer?

Comment: @Skooba I am asking Why character started the topic **disclaimer** suddenly?

Comment: This is a perfectly on-topic  question about the motivations of a character.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a joke about controversies over commercials for real toys, in which the toys may be shown acting on their own, without children playing with them.  For example, this infamous Food Fighters commercial was accused of giving children the impression that the toys were more independent than they actually were:

It's cut off at the end of the YouTube video, but there was a very quickly spoken disclaimer at the end of the television ad:  "Toys do not walk and talk."  Consumer advocates were not necessarily satisfied with that disclaimer, though legally the extant disclaimer was probably sufficient to avoid any liability for false advertising.

Reference to this is funny *Small Soldiers*, because the usual issue (which is that the toys cannot move and act on their own) does not apply.

Comment: Your last sentence is off - when this conversation take place, the toys don't move on their own. In fact it's only because of this that they get the idea to make them smarter and more autonomous.

Comment: Yeah, but it's still funny because the audience usually knows by the time they watch it it's a movie about toys actually moving on their own.

Answer (score 3):

Part of it is a dig at disclaimers in general. [From the New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/1997/03/05/business/warning-maybe-too-much-of-a-good-thing.html), shortly before Small Soldiers was released

> Don't say you haven't been warned.
>
> Visit a toy store and read the labels. Metal-tipped darts, you will be advised, can cause puncture wounds. Hockey sticks can inflict severe bodily harm. Flimsy plastic helmets offer no protection from bicycle or construction accidents. Do not tow a child, you will be told, on a sled behind your car.
>
> And if you buy a certain Batman costume, you will see the following:
>
> > ''PARENT: Please exercise caution -- FOR PLAY ONLY: Mask and chest plate are not protective: cape does not enable user to fly.''

This is also a combo of these TV Tropes: [Our Lawyers Advised Us](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OurLawyersAdvisedThisTrope) and the [Corrupt Corporate Executive](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CorruptCorporateExecutive). So the lawyers said they were covered. Which makes it OK. For them. You were warned...